# Nextjs project deploy in cPanel issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, next.js, cpanel

I am trying to deploy a nextjs project in cPanel. The project has only one SSG page. When I set basePath in next.config.js to deploy the project, the page is showing a 404 page not found and continuously calls the page in the network tab. I have tried to solve the issue in several ways. But I can't. Do you have any idea what is the issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDiYB.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZvgC.png)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Replace this line from the file "\node_modules\next\dist\build\handle-externals.js".

From:

return `commonjs ${localRes.replace(/.*?next[/\\]dist/, "next/dist")}`

To:

return `commonjs ${localRes.replace(/.*?next[/\\]dist/, "next/dist").replace(/\\/g, "/")}`

Around Line 178 /179

if it exists